# Create a transparent scroll pane in java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, transparent

Is it possible to make a `JScrollPane` completely transparent, in order to show what's underneath it, but leave the elements of the list I need to scroll completely unaltered?

Comment: Do you want to just toggle the visibility of the panel itself? That would be `panelName.setVisible(false)`?

Comment: If I do this, the components on it are made invisible along with the panel, but I would like them to stay.

Comment: (1-) *the scrolling pane should be transparent. Do you have any idea how to do that?* - yes, but you haven't updated your question with the "MRE" and all the relevant information about the question. We should not need to read all the comments to find out the real requirement. The question as stated has been answered.

Comment: yes, you're right, I edited the question and I will provide an example as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to ovveride the paint method of a JPanel in order to make it completely transparent to show what's underneath it

Don't override paint().

Instead you just use:

```
panel.setOpaque( false );
```

to make the panel transparent.

All the components added to the panel will be displayed normally based on the rules of the layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but not by overriding `paint()` method, it's never a good idea to override it, probably `paintComponent()` but still there are simpler ways to do it.

1. Create a `JFrame`
2. Create a `JPanel` which will be the background
3. Create a `JPanel` which will be the top pane
4. Set the background of the `bgPane` to some color
5. Set the background of the `topPane` to other color (Optional) - Just for you to see what happens on step 7
6. Add a `JLabel` to the `topPane`
7. `setOpaque(false)` to the `topPane`
8. Voila! You should be able to see through the other pane

[image]

> *If I try to setOpaque(false) the top panel and the JScrollPane wrapped around it, all I see is gray, and the background is covered by this gray.*

For that all you have to do is:

```
scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what @camickr suggested, and it works fine in many cases, but not with a JScrollPane. If I try to `setOpaque(false)` the top panel and the `JScrollPane` wrapped around it, all I see is gray, and the background is covered by this gray. I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. My objective would be to scroll a series of thin custom JPanels while viewing the background, thus the scrolling pane should be transparent. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Then please add those details to your question and a [mre] of what you've tried and why hasn't it worked

Comment: @reaper_ what about using setOpaque(false) on the JScrollPane

Comment: @Frakcool Thank you for your answer, unfortunately using `setOpaque(false)` on the viewport is still not working. I will try to provide a specific example if I can manage to recreate it in a comprehensible way.